# Making a deep related field searchable in OctoberCMS

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

My my `columns.yaml` file for the `Invoice` model I have the following column:

```
transaction[user][email]:
    label: Login email
    type: text
    searchable: true // doesn't work!
```

Unfortunately, the `searchable` bit doesn't work and I understand that this is because I am using `transaction[user][email]` instead of having a `relation` and `select` as part of the column.

My question is, can I somehow use `relation` and `select` when I'm going 2 relations deep, like this, or do I need a different approach?

My `Invoice` model has this relation defined:

```
public $morphOne = [
    'transaction' => ['Namespace\Plugin\Models\Transaction', 'name' => 'transactionable']
];
```

And my `Transaction` model has this relation defined:

```
public $belongsTo = [
    'user' => ['Rainlab\User\Models\User'],
];
```

So, essentially, I want to be able have a backend list of invoices with the user's email address showing in one of the columns, and also make it possible for an email address to be entered in the search box in order to filter the list only for invoices associated with the user with that email address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm, I tried one demo in my local and its working just fine.

In Your `Controller` add this code `we are going to extend query` to add our `custom field` which can be `searchable` even its `2 relation deeper`

```
<?php

use Rainlab\User\Models\User;
use Namespace\Plugin\Models\Invoice;
use Namespace\Plugin\Models\Transaction;

... your controller code ...

public function listExtendQuery($query)
{

    $invoiceTableName = (new Invoice)->getTable();
    $transactionTableName = (new Transaction)->getTable();
    $userTableName = (new User)->getTable();

    $query->addSelect($userTableName . '.email as email');

    $query->leftJoin($transactionTableName, $invoiceTableName . '.id', '=', $transactionTableName . '.invoice_id');
    $query->leftJoin($userTableName, $userTableName . '.id', '=', $transactionTableName . '.user_id');

}

...
```

and now inside your `columns.yaml` add this

```
columns:
    id:
        label: id
        type: number
        invisible: false

    ... other columns 

    email:
        label: user_email
        type: text
        default: none
        searchable: true
        select: email
```

now you are able to `search from email` as well, hope this will work

if you get any error please comment.

Comment: Thank you, once again @Hardik Satasiya for a clear and concise answer and a solution to my problem! :-)

Comment: glad, it helped you out :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with this solution, when you try to search, it runs query for count records and throws exception "column not found", because in count query it doesn't have select statement but only "select count  ..." in my case it looks like -
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cruises.pagetitle' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `cruises` left join `cr_cab` as `crc` on `crc`.`cab_id` = `cruises`.`id` left join `chartercruise` as `chrc` on `chrc`.`id` = `crc`.`cruise_id` where ... or (lower(cruises.pagetitle) LIKE %thaty%))))" on line 664 of C:\xampp\htdocs\12knots_october\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php

columns.yaml
        pagetitle:
        label: 'Connected Cruise' 
        type: text
        default: none
        searchable: true
        sortable: true

```
    public function listExtendQueryBefore($query) {

    $query->addSelect('chrc.pagetitle');
    $query->leftJoin('cr_cab as crc', 'crc.cab_id', '=', 'cruises.id');
    $query->leftJoin('chartercruise as chrc', 'chrc.id', '=', 
                                                         'crc.cruise_id');

     }
```